# Attempting to loop back to the beginning to run my program again

Tags: c++, loops, nested

I am currently writing a code where in my main function I am just calling other functions. I am attempting to reloop back to the begining so the user can run the program again. The main function is just to call functions so my question is I know it is not possible to go back to the main function, but is it possible to create a function that will loop all other functions again?  I feel as though I tried everything and continue to get infinite loops. I attached my code.
**To condense the code please understand that all variables/classes are declared**

```
void instructions();
void full_outputs(string, double, double, double);

int main()
{
    instructions();

    employee_num = employee_ID();
    //cout << employee_num << " This is the employee ID."<<endl;
    base_salary = baseSalary();
    //cout << base_salary << " This is the employee's base salary." <<endl;
    per_commission = percentage_commission();
    //cout << per_commission << " This is the employee's percentage commission." << endl;
    base_commission = base_and_com(base_salary, per_commission);
    cout<< base_commission << "This is the total base salary with comission" << endl;
    gross_pay = grossPay(base_commission);
    //cout << gross_pay << "This is the gross pay"<<endl;
    state_tax_hold = stateTax_hold(gross_pay);
    //cout<< state_tax_hold << "This is the state tax hold on the amount" <<endl;
    fica_total = ficaTotal(gross_pay);
    //cout << fica_total << " This is the fica hold on the amount" <<endl;
    fed_tax = fedTax(gross_pay);
    //cout << fed_tax << " THis is the federal tax hold on the amount" << endl;
    total_tax_hold = withholding_total(state_tax_hold, fica_total, fed_tax);
    //cout << total_tax_hold << " This is the total tax withholding" << endl;
    net_pay = netPay(total_tax_hold, gross_pay);
    //cout << net_pay << " This is the total net pay" << endl;



    full_outputs(employee_num, gross_pay, total_tax_hold, net_pay);




    return 0;   
}

void instructions()
{
    cout << " This program will process sales employee's base salary \n";
    cout << " and their percentage commission. \n";
    cout << " You will be prompted to enter the employee's ID, base salary \n";
    cout << " and percentage commission. \n";
    cout << " \n";
    cout << " The program will terminate if unspecified characters are used. \n";

}



string employee_ID()
{
        string employee_num;

        cout << " Please enter the employees eight digit ID number" << endl;
        cin >> employee_num;

    return employee_num;
}



double baseSalary()
{
        double base_salary;

        cout << " Please enter the employees base salary " << endl;
        cin >> base_salary;

    return base_salary;

}


float percentage_commission()
{
        float per_commission;

        cout << " Please enter the employees percentage commission."<< endl;
        cout << " Please do not enter the percent symbol." << endl;
        cout << " Percentage commission is between 0.05% - 10%" << endl;
        cin >> per_commission;
        while ((per_commission < 0.05)||(per_commission > 10))
        {

            cout << "The commission rate is not between 0.05% and 10%" << endl;
            cout << "Please try again " << endl;
            cin >> per_commission;

        }
        per_commission = per_commission / PERCENT_TO_DECIMAL;

    return per_commission;

}

double base_and_com(double base_salary, float per_commission)
{
    double base_commission;
    double total;
    total = base_salary*per_commission;
    base_commission = total + base_salary;


    return base_commission;

}



double grossPay(double base_commission)
{
        double gross_pay;

        gross_pay = base_commission;

        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    return gross_pay;
}


double stateTax_hold(double gross_pay)
{
        double state_tax_hold;
        state_tax_hold= gross_pay*STATE_TAX;

    return state_tax_hold;
}


double ficaTotal (double gross_pay)
{
        double fica_total;
        fica_total = gross_pay* FICA; 

    return fica_total;  
}


double fedTax (double gross_pay)
{
        double fed_tax;
        if (gross_pay <= 500)
        {
            fed_tax = gross_pay * FEDERAL_TAX_UNDER;
        }
        else
        {
            fed_tax = gross_pay * FEDERAL_TAX_OVER;
        }
    return fed_tax;
}


double withholding_total(double fed_tax, double fica_total, double state_tax_hold )
{
        double tax_withholding_total;

        tax_withholding_total = fed_tax + fica_total + state_tax_hold;
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    return tax_withholding_total;


}



double netPay(double total_tax_hold, double gross_pay)
{
        double net_pay;

        net_pay = (gross_pay - total_tax_hold);
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    return net_pay;

}

void full_outputs(string employee_num, double gross_pay, double total_tax_hold, double net_pay)
{
    cout << " The employee ID : " << right << employee_num << endl; 
    cout << " The gross pay is: " << right << gross_pay << endl;
    cout << " The total tax withholding amount is : " << right << total_tax_hold << endl; 
    cout << " The net pay is: " << right << net_pay << endl; 

}
```

Comment: You could make the contents of `int main()` into a different function and call that in a loop in a new `int main()` and be done in 5 or less new lines.

Comment: Why not just put all of the code in main inside a loop? (similar to what @dre is saying).

Comment: If you want to loop back to the start of main, make the body of main a loop.

Comment: @drescherjm I will fix it to make it less code. First time on here. Thank you

Comment: @scohe001 dre It is a very strange request, but I am not suppose to put anything inside the main function other than calls to other functions. If these were not the circumstances I would most definitely just loop the main function.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Right now your program does X, then Y, then Z. You want it to do XYZXYZXYZ, right? But you can't change `main` at all? How are you supposed to change the functionality then?

Answer (score 3):

As you know, in main you can just have a while loop with the code you want to repeat inside it:

```
int main()
{
    // this will loop forever, until you explicitly break or return
    while (true) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

... but since you are constrained by the artificial limitation of only having function calls in main...

```
void run()
{
    // this will loop forever, until you explicitly break or return
    while (true) {
        // your code here
    }
}

int main()
{
    run();
}
```